# Android/python : is ttsSpeak non blocking?

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I have written a small app on Android using python (Qpython3) with voice synthesizer & voice recognition.

```
droid = sl4a.Android()
droid.ttsSpeak("hello")
v = str(droid.recognizeSpeech()
droid.ttsSpeak(v)
```

The synthesized voice is then saying a first "hello", and then once again it says "hello" as if it was auto-recording the first string - and I interpret this as ttsSpeak non blocking.
Is there a way to wait for the completion of the voice synthesizer before starting the voice recognizer ?

Comment: looks like ttsSpeak is non blocking. now how to wait for completion of speak : I have tried to loop until droid.ttsIsSpeaking() is false. but it loops forever.

Answer (score 0):

found in [In Love with a Droid](http://android-scripting.blogspot.fr/2010/11/first-android-experiment-smssenderpy.html)
need to wait via ttsIsSpeaking which returns a tuple, the boolean is the second element of the tuple is set false when the current speak has completed.